# tooltip with names in a PCA plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, tooltip, pca, r-plotly

I want to generate an interactive plot with ggplotly(). The tooltip should show me the name of the variable.

```
interactive <- ggplotly(pca,dynamicTicks = T,tooltip = c("x","y",label = list))
```

pca is a visualization of a PCA. 
sub is a data.frame that contains variable names.

```
sub <- PCA(dataframe)

pca <- fviz_pca_ind(sub, pointsize = "cos2", 
             pointshape = 21, fill = "#E7B800",
             repel = TRUE, # Avoid text overlapping (slow if many points)
             geom = c("text","point"), 
             xlab = "PC1", ylab = "PC2",label = animal_list
             )
```

dataframe contains variable names and I want interactive to show those in the tooltip. `tooltip =` does not help me much and changing properties in pca_individuals (like with `label=` or something is not working either.
Thank you for your kind support.
I really appreciate your altruistic behaviour.

For playing around (the actual data frame is muuch bigger):

```
dataframe <- data_frame("c1"=c(78,89,0),"c2"=c(89,89,34),"c3"=c(56,0,4))
```

Comment: What is `dataframe` (`PCA(dataframe)`) and `data_frame` ? Please provide a reproducible code.

Comment: `PCA(dataframe)` does not work (no numerical variables). Please provide a reproducible code.

Comment: reprex fixed, I guess. Thank you for your coment @StéphaneLaurent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can manually do the contents of the tooltips as follows:

```
library(factoextra)
library(plotly)
library(FactoMineR)

dataframe <- 
  data.frame("c1"=c(78,89,0),"c2"=c(89,89,34),"c3"=c(56,0,4))
res.pca <- PCA(dataframe)

pca <- fviz_pca_ind(res.pca, pointsize = "cos2", 
                    pointshape = 21, fill = "#E7B800",
                    repel = TRUE, 
                    geom = c("text","point"), 
                    xlab = "PC1", ylab = "PC2")

ggly <- ggplotly(pca)
bggly <- plotly_build(ggly)
bggly$x$data[[1]]$text <- 
  with(pca$data, paste0("name: ", name, 
                        "</br></br>x: ", x, 
                        "</br>y: ", y, 
                        "</br>coord: ", coord, 
                        "</br>cos2: ", cos2, 
                        "</br>contrib: ", contrib))

bggly
```